# Deducing countable additivity from continuity and finite additivity.

Tags: probability

> Show that the axiom that $P$ is countably additive is equivalent to
>   the axiom that $P$ is finitely additive and continuous. That is to
>   say, let $\Omega$ be a set and $\mathscr{F}$ an event space of subsets
>   of $Omega$. If $P$ is a mapping from $\mathscr{F}$ into $[0,1]$
>   satisfying $i) P(\Omega)=1, P(\emptyset)=0,$   $ii) if A,B \in
> > \mathscr{F} and A \cup B=\emptyset then P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B),$
>
> $iii) if A_1,A_2,... \in \mathscr{F} and A_i\subset A_{i+1} for
> > I=1,2,..., then P(A)=lim_{t\to \infty}P(A_i)$
>
> where $A=\cup_{t=1}^{\infty}A_i$,
>
> there $P$ satisfies $P(\cup_{t=1}^{\infty}A_i)=\sum_tP(A_t)$ for all
>   sequences $A_1,A_2,...$ of disjoint events.

So here is my attempts:
define $B_i=A_1 \cup A_2\cup...\cup A_i$, then $B_i\subset B_{i+1}$. So $P(\cup_{t=1}^{\infty}A_i)=P(\cup_{t=1}^{\infty}B_i)=lim_{t\to \infty}P(B_i)=lim_{t\to \infty}(P(A_1)+P(A_2)+...+P(A_i))$. I'm now stuck as I'm wondering if I can just write at infinite, the limit becomes $\sum_tP(A_t)$?

Comment: Recall the definition of infinite sums like $\sum_{t=1}^\infty P(A_t)$.

Comment: Ah so by definition, the result follows!